# Do negative binomials imply negative factorials exist?

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, factorial, negative-binomial

I've seen the following identity:

$$\binom{-n}{k} = (-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}$$

So I tried to derive it, assuming negative factorial was a real concept, having it extend down to negative infinity:

$$\binom{-n}{k} =  \frac{(-n)!}{k!(-n-k)!}$$

Expanding to

$$\frac{(-n)(-n-1)(-n-2)...}{k!(-n-k)(-n-k-1)(-n-k-2)...}$$

Reframing to

$$\frac{(-(n))(-(n+1))(-(n+2))...}{k!(-(n+k)-(n+k+1)-(n+k+2)...)}$$

Simplifying to

$$\frac{(-(n))(-(n+1))(-(n+2))...(-(n+k-2))(-(n+k-1))}{k!}$$

Then

$$(-1)^k\frac{(n)(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k-2)(n+k-1)}{k!}$$

Which also equals

$$(-1)^k\frac{(n-1)!(n)(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k-2)(n+k-1)}{(n-1)!k!}$$

or

$$(-1)^k\frac{(n+k-1)!}{k!(n-1)!}$$

or

$$(-1)^k \binom{n+k-1}{k}$$

I am a little surprised that it seemed to work. Was this a happy coincidence? What does this imply for the factorial if I was able to treat it as something going down to negative infinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Factorials of negative integers don't exist under usual definitions.

---

**Proving the identity:**

Using the definition of the [generalized binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series):

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{k!}~~~~~~\text{where}~n\in\Bbb C, k\in\Bbb N$$

where $n^{\underline{k}}=\underbrace{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+2)(n-k+1)}_{k~\text{terms}}$ is the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

We have:

$\begin{array}{rlr}\binom{-n}{k}&=\frac{(-n)^{\underline{k}}}{k!}\\
&=\frac{(-n)(-n-1)(-n-2)\cdots(-n-k+2)(-n-k+1)}{k!}\\
&=\frac{(-n)(-n-1)(-n-2)\cdots(-n-k+2)(-n-k+1)}{k!}\cdot (-1)^{k}\cdot (-1)^k&\text{as}~((-1)^k)^2=1\\
\color{red}{(\dagger)}&=\frac{(n)(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k-2)(n+k-1)}{k!}\cdot (-1)^k&\text{distributing}~(-1)^k~\text{across numerator}\\
&=\frac{(n+k-1)(n+k-2)\cdots (n+2)(n+1)(n)}{k!}\cdot (-1)^k&\text{rearranging numerator}\\
&=\frac{((n+k-1))((n+k-1)-1)\cdots ((n+k-1)-k+2)((n+k-1)-k+1)}{k!}\cdot(-1)^k&\text{rewriting terms in numerator}\\
&=\frac{(n+k-1)^{\underline{k}}}{k!}\cdot (-1)^k&\text{recognizing falling factorial}\\
&=\binom{n+k-1}{k}\cdot (-1)^k&\text{generalized binomial coeffecient}\end{array}$

Technically, we could have stopped sooner at $\color{red}{(\dagger)}$ had we noted that $\frac{n^{\overline{k}}}{k!}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ where $n^\overline{k}$ is the rising factorial, $n^\overline{k}=n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k-1)$.

**Comments about involvement of negative factorials:**

Factorials of negative numbers do not appear in the above proof or definitions at all.  In fact, going to the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), a generalization of factorials to all complex numbers, one has that $\Gamma(n)$ is a [pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_(complex_analysis)) for all negative integers $n$ (*similar to a division by zero error*).

Ignoring this, if you try to look at something like $(-5)!$ as $(-5)(-6)(-7)(-8)\cdots=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{k=5}^n (-k)$, as an [infinite product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) it will clearly diverge as the related infinite series $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=5}^n\ln(-k)$ diverges.

---

As for your algebra implying the negative factorial's existence, that would be a happy accident due to the cancellations involved.  In terms of logical implications, $P\Rightarrow \text{True}$ does not imply that $P$ is true.  By assuming it exists, you concluded a true statement, but that by itself does not prove that it exists.

Comment: It seems like the generalized binomial coefficient is the same as the "derivation" I made except it (roughly) skips straight to the part after the cancelling out the "infinite" tails on the numerator and denominator. Is this just a matter of convenience? I understand that the generalized definition is consistent with the positive-factorial definition, but how do we know it also extends to the negative properly? What makes it a non-arbitrary definition?

Comment: I suppose what I am saying is that if the usual binomial coefficient definition involves factorials, why do we even learn this definition if it doesn't extend to the negatives, if we are to say that negative binomials exist?

Comment: @KaliMa The original definition was created for the sole purpose of answering questions about discrete objects.  "How many subsets of size $k$ exist from an $n$ element set."  There is no such thing as a set with a fractional amount of elements, just as there is no such thing as a set with a negative number of elements or a non-real number of elements.  Because of the usefulness of the binomial coefficient to algebra (*and not just combinatorics*) it was *extended* to include additional arguments to talk about things like $(x+y)^n$ where $n$ is no longer restricted to non-negative integers.

Comment: @KaliMa the intuition used in defining the basic version of the binomial coefficient as a counting tool is useful to learn as similar arguments can be used to solve many counting problems.  The generalized version, although useful, loses a great deal of its intuitive nature.